# How to create a pivot in anaconda python in below format from given data using pivot _table

Tags: python, anaconda, pivot-table

This is the input data want to create pivot in below format:

[image]

I need output of pivot table in below format:

[image]

Comment: See [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html#pivot)

Comment: I written code like this                                                     table=input.pivot_table(index=['Department', 'Brand Name', 'Purchase Type Desc',
       'BRAND TYPE', 'Item Code', 'MRP', 'Pack Indicator'],columns=['country', 'location'],values=['On Ord Qty','sale qty'],aggfunc=sum,margins=True,fill_value=0,margins_name="Totals")                         But output is not satisfactory

Answer (score 1):

Guys finally myself got the answer:

```
pivot_model = multiindex_input.pivot_table(
    index=[
        'Department', 'Class', 'Subclass', 'Pri Sup Name', 
        'Brand Name', 'Purchase Type Desc', 
        'BRAND TYPE', 'Item Code', 'Style', 
        'Secondary Desc', 'MRP', 'Pack Indicator'
    ],
    aggfunc=sum,
    values=['On Ord Qty', 'sale qty'],
    columns=['Country','State'],
    margins=True,
    fill_value=0
)

pivot_model.columns=pivot_model.columns.swaplevel(2,0)
pivot_model.head(2)
```